# Create package from four unique projects not under same parent?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am fairly new to Maven and working on below.

**Problem:**

I have 4 individual projects. NOT UNDER ONE PARENT

```
Project 1
 -POM.xml (creates project1.jar)
Project 2 (Dependency on project 1)
 -POM.xml (creates project2.jar)
Project 3 (Dependency on project 1 and Project 2)
 -POM.xml (creates project3.jar)
Project 4
 -POM.xml (creates project4.jar)
```

I am able to make build for individual projects i.e. able to create .jar file.

**Issue:**

Instead of building individual projects, I would like to create a package e.g-xyz.zip file which has all 4 project jars in single run rather than running it 4 times

**What I tried**

I created on separate project e.g: project 5 which has POM.xml and add all 4 projects as module

```
...
<modules>
<module>project1</module>
<module>project2</module>
<module>project3</module>
<module>project4</module>
</modules>
...
```

Appreciate you inputs

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Alekshandr M - How to create package for projects not under same parent?

Comment: @MindPeace What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want an ear file containing those 4 jars? Do you want to output those 4 jars in the same target directory?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new module (type pom), that has dependencies on the 4 modules and use the assembly plugin to create the zip.